# Is it possible to replace the following code by lambda:

Tags: java, lambda, stringtokenizer

```
static TreeMap<Integer, String> parseElementsBeforeOpenBracket(String inValue) {
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(inValue, "[]", true);
    TreeMap<Integer, String> mapElements = new TreeMap<>();
    int i = 0;
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
        String s = (String) tokenizer.nextElement();
        mapElements.put(i, s);
        i += s.length();
    }
    return mapElements;
}
```

Expecting: something like
TreeMap<Integer, String> mapElements = xxx.stream()...Collectors.toMap()

Comment: I would advice against using a lambda. The current process has a state (variable `i`). While we can introduce states in lambdas, this is discouraged.

Comment: I would advise against using `StringTokenizer`: [StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#nextElement()) So something of that great age is not going to be a natural fit with modern Java features. Please give an example of the text you're processing

Comment: The example of the text is
"ozh2[ 2a]xyz4[ 4b3[ 3c]]abc5[ 5]abcde"
The method is part of the solution of the problem where pattern like "2[abcd]" is substituted by "abcdabcd". Patterns like 4[ 4b3[ 3c]] with "child" sub-patterns are allowed.

Comment: I tried to use String.split, but I failed to find proper argument to include both '[' and ']'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use lambda, but, as the official doc says you can use `Mathch` and `Pattern` under `java.util.regex` package instead of `StringTokenizer`:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[^\\[\\]]+|\\[|\\]");
    
    public static TreeMap<Integer, String> parseElementsBeforeOpenBracket(String inValue) {
        TreeMap<Integer, String> mapElements = new TreeMap<>();
        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(inValue);
        int i = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String s = matcher.group();
            mapElements.put(i, s);
            i += s.length();
        }
        return mapElements;
    }
```

I tested with `ozh22a]xyz4[4b3[3c]]abc5[5]abcde` and got the same result as your code `{0=ozh22a, 6=], 7=xyz4, 11=[, 12=4b3 , 15=[, 16=3c, 18=], 19=], 20=abc5, 24=[, 25=5, 26=], 27=abcde}`

Maybe you can't think of `[^\\[\\]]+|\\[|\\]` very quickly, but observing your code results can be divided into three parts:

1. Consecutive characters that are not `[` or `]` -> `[^\\[\\]]+`
2. `[` -> `\\[`
3. `]` -> `\\]`

`\\` is an escape

If you are not familiar with the methods of the `Matcher` class, please see [Module java.base Package java.util.regex Class Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

If you use jdk9 and above, you can use the `Matcher.result()` method, such as `matcher.results().collect(TreeMap::new, (map, matchResult) -> map.put(matchResult.start(), matchResult.group()), TreeMap::putAll);`

This can directly get a TreeMap result.

Please see  [Matcher.results()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results()).I didn't test it because I'm using JDK8.

I am not very good at English, I use Google Translate, which may affect reading, please forgive me.
Hope to help you.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I was not familiar with Matcher

Comment: You can try to learn it, because `StringTokenizer` is obsolete. @aozhinsky